# xmlschema format

Tags: xml, xsd

What is the proper format to define a schema for an xml element which contains **Attribute,Sub-elements and Subelements also contains SUB-ELEMENTS**
For eg:  **My xml**

```
<element1 attribute1="hello">
 <element-sub1>
       <element-sub-sub1 attribute-sub-1="hi"/>
 <elementsubsub1>
</element1>
```

I tried with the following schema

```
         <xs:element name="element1">
         <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="element-sub1" type="xs:anyType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          <xs:complexType> 
          <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="element-sub-sub1" type="xs:anyType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="attribute-sub-1" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:complexType>

          </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="attribute1" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
```

But I am getting the following error

```
The content of 'sequence' must match (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*). A problem was found st
arting at: complexType.
```

Why am I getting this error? What is the right format to write schema for my requirement?
**NOTE**
Element "element-sub-sub1" may have text also.
**UPDATE 1**

```
<element1 URI="">
 <element-sub1>
 <element-sub-sub1 Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
 <element-sub-sub1 Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116">
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
Pan : <xsl:copy-of select="//Pp"/>

MobileNo : <xsl:copy-of select="//Mm"/>

TotalAmount : <xsl:copy-of select="//Total"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
 element-sub-sub1
 </element-sub1>
 </element1>
```

Comment: Ok, now I see you want the stylesheet element to be optional. Check out my edited answer (yet again). I added the minOccurs, maxOccurs attributes to allow 0 or 1 stylesheet inside a sub-sub1

Comment: @Tom still same error.Element 'any' is Invalid

Comment: then try with the import. I'll have a look at this later. I've got my own job to do besides yours ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs of all, you can't have a `type="xs:anyType"` attribute and an `<xs:complexType>` element on the same `<xs:element>`

Secondly, a definition of `<xs:complexType>` may only appear immediately inside an `<xs:element>` or as a global type as a child of `<schema>`

Last, but not least. If you want an element to contain attributes, make its type complex.

```
    <xs:element name="element1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element-sub1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="element-sub-sub1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="attribute-sub-1" type="xs:string" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="attribute1" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

As mentioned in the comments, the  element allows you to insert any xml element on that position. The validation will pass, no matter if the element is actually valid according to some standard or not. It just has to be well-formed.

If you want to validate the entire stylesheet, use an `xs:import` to gain access to the namespace, where xsl stylesheets are defined: http://www.w3.org/XML/2000/04schema-hacking/xslt.xsd and reference the stylesheet or transform element in your xsd.
Inside `<xs:element name="sub-sub1>` :

```
                            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                    <xs:element ref="xsl:stylesheet"/>
                                    <xs:element ref="xsl:transform"/>
                                <xs:choice>
                                <!-- You'll have to define a prefix for the xslt namespace imported -->
                                <xs:attribute name="attribute-sub-1" type="xs:string" />
                            </xs:complexType>
```

The choice element allows you to use one of two accepted top tags for an XSL stylesheet, `<stylesheet`> or `<transform>`

UPDATE: added the minOccurs, maxOccurs attributes for optional stylesheets/transforms

Comment: Thanks for the Help. I forgot to mention one more thing. My element "element-sub-sub1" should contain text also.

Comment: @Mr.Jain you'll need to set the mixed attribute on complexType. mixed="true" Check my edited answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly. But I got into another trouble. For my  "element-sub-sub1",the text value is                                "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"             version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>.
<xsl:template match="/">" So it takes <xsl:stylesheet> as a child element and shows error.

Comment: You mentioned plain text, not another set of xml elements. For an entire XSLT, I think the most sensible solution would be to insert one more <xs:element> with the type of type="xs:anyType" inside the most nested <xs:complexType>

Comment: Cant we do something to parse it as a text??

Comment: @Mr.Jain my bad, an xs:any is more appropriate (now you can put any xml element in there, even a complex one, such as a transform). Parse it? I'm not sure what you mean. If the only element that you can put there is an xsl stylesheet, it's possible to import the xsd defining xsl and reference the stylesheet/transform element from within your complexType.

Comment: I mean to make <xsl:stylesheet> element look like a text only instead as xml element

Comment: @Mr.Jain do you want it to be validated as well? If you don't need it to, the <xs:any/> should suffice. If you want to validate it, you'll need an import and a reference, as I said in the previous comment.

Comment: I need not validate xsl:stylesheet thing. I just want while validating the Transform element, the  xsl:stylesheet part should not show any error

Comment: I tried with <any/> and I am getting the following error org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C://xml//c5.xsd; lineNumber: 27;
columnNumber: 17; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_Transform
TransformsReferenceSignedInfoSignature' is invalid.  Element 'any' is invalid, m
isplaced, or occurs too often.

Comment: @Mr.Jain please update your question to include the whole document, along with your XSL.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema isn't valid and even well-formed. Here's what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:test:1">

   <xs:element name="element1">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element-sub1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="element-sub-sub1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:attribute name="attribute-sub-1" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
         <xs:attribute name="attribute1" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: For the example document from question, you got the attribute-sub1 on the wrong element.

Comment: @Grzegorz Grzybek My basic requirement is answered by Tom properly but I got into another trouble. It is there in comments of Tom's answer. Just check whether u can clarify